# How to run Facebook application from my application

Tags: android, facebook, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I want to start from my appcelerator (Android) application the Facebook application.
I'm building this code:

```
function launchFacebook(){
    try{
        var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
            action : Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER,
            packageName: 'com.facebook',
            className : 'com.facebook.FacebookActivity"'
        });

        Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
   }catch(e){
    console.log("errore mentre lancio l app di facebook");
   }
}
```

but if I try to run this method, the Facebook application not starter.
How can I start the Facebook application from my app?

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: This is the strnage, I don't have never error. the code is execute but the facebook app is not run

Comment: There seems to be a number of questions concerning [activities that are started but nothing is seen](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+start+activity+but+not+show&oq=android+launch+activity+but+not&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3j69i64.10926j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=android+starting+activity+but+nothing+happens). You should read through these.

Comment: did you try the packageName : com.facebook.katana and declare the activity in your tiapp.xml file?

Comment: @PrashantSaini how can I declare that activity in my trap.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying this code and works.

```
   try{
        var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
            action : Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER,
            packageName: 'com.facebook.katana',
            className : 'com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity'
        });
        Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
   }catch(e){
        Ti.API.error("ERRORE "+e.message);
   }
```